# CSS div positioning using co-ordinates

Tags: javascript, css, random

I'm currently coding a simple game in javascript. The game takes place in a `div`, called *#box*. And the enemy is a `div` called *#enemy* .

```
       <div id="box">
                <div id="prepend">
                    <div id="hero"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="enemy"></div>
       </div>
```

Inside this #box the #enemy will move about using a `setInterval()` function generating random numbers (animating to x, y) . However, when I do this, somehow the point of origin where the coordinates start is at top left hand corner of the window when it should be in the top left hand corner in the *#box*. This is how I have been trying to generate random numbers to keep the *#enemy* inside the *#box*

```
var test = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1500 - $("#box").offset().left) + 0),
    test2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (750 - $("#box").offset().top) + 0);
```

But the problem I obviously have is that it keeps animating outside the *#box*.

CSS :

```
    #box{
    width:640px;
    height:400px;
    float: left;
    background:url(../png/space.jpg);
    margin: 0 0 0 100px;
    }   
    #enemy {
    width: 69px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 100px 0 0 100px;
    background:url(../png/target2.png);
    z-index:2;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The container div needs to have `position: relative`. Otherwise the position of the window, or the closest parent element with a `relative` position will be used in determining the inner `div`'s position. By making the parent have a *relative* position, the child `div` will position itself *relative* to its parent as opposed to relative to the window.

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
position: relative;
```

in your `#box` CSS, for the absolute position on your `#enemy` to be relative to the box.

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: relative;` to #box to make #enemy position relative to #box.

Answer (score 0):

To make `#box`es children position relative to it, you can use any of the following depending on your requirements:

```
#box { position: absolute; }
#box { position: relative; }
#box { position: fixed; }
```